# Xcode 4.5 Base Localization and NSSegmentedControl issue

Tags: localization, nssegmentedcontrol

I can't make my NSSegmentedControl change its titles using Base Localization.

Xcode generates the files for english and french languages, I translate the titles of each segment, but they remain the same as in the xib file.

Same thing for the tool tips of an other segmented control.

As everything else is working perfectly fine, I suppose this is a bug for this particular type of control.

Can somebody else confirm this problem? (Xcode 4.5.2, MacOS 10.8.2)

Comment: Seeing the same problem with UISegmentedControl on iOS 6.0 with base internationalization.

Comment: Did you perform a clean build? Xcode doesn't recognize newly added localizations until then - at least true for OS X projects and Xcode up to 6.4

Answer (score 1):

Works like a breeze for me.

**Things to watch out for:**

- **Clean the build folder**. When you've just added the `.strings` file for new translations the old file (non-localized) can still hang around in the old location. This can cause the system to ignore your localized resources.
- **Make sure everything ends up in your bundle**. To to the built binary in Finder and check its contents. Sometimes files are missing from the copy step, not included in the target, etc. so they don't end up in the built bundle.